# How to add settings file in parent directory of Google App Engine (Node.js)

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

Hello for my nodejs app I use a settings.js file (with DB information, cloud-keys etc..), which is in the parent directory above my project.

Thus I don't need to add this into the git repository.

In Azure I just upload it in the parent directory above the project via FTP once and let it there, but in google cloud I am not sure if this is possible.

What are the options to store settings outside the project directory in google cloud?

Thanks for any help and advices

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you want to upload the file "settings.js" info to the cloud so your App can reach this info without deploying it with the rest of your application (by locating this file with your app.yaml file)

There are some options to manage [files and information with App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/using-third-party-databases). If you want to store this info in a dynamic way (keys, DB name, root, etc...) you can use [Firestore in Datastore mode](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/using-cloud-datastore). This will let you store settings parameters in an easy and very maintainable way.

On the other hand, if you want to be able to upload and update files instead of putting your info in a database you can use [Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/using-cloud-storage).

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. But if I use for example Google Cloud Storage for my settings file, do I not still need to maintain somewhere the google cloud key for accessing it?

Comment: In order to store your key you can use the [Key Service Management](https://cloud.google.com/kms/docs/quickstart).